# Solr geospatial and CakePHP: boost using geodist()

Tags: php, cakephp, solr, geospatial

I have a CakePHP 1.3 application connecting to Solr 3.3 search.

There are two documents with the same attributes except for their lat/lon. The doc with closer lat/lon was entered second (higher id) but with the bost from geodist() I expect it to appear first. Actual behavior is doc with closer lat/lon appears second. Here's the array the PHP Solr service hands back to my app:

```
protected '_rawResponse' => string '{
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":0,
        "params":{
            "start":"0",
            "q":"beethoven eroica",
            "sfield":"lat_lon",
            "pt":"45.3306,-122.5290",
            "bf":"recip(geodist(),1,1000,1000)",
            "json.nl":"map",
            "wt":"json",
            "rows":"10",
            "version":"1.4"
        }
    },
    "response":{
        "numFound":7,
        "start":0,
        "docs":[{
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Symphony No 3, Eroica",
            "composer":"Beethoven, Ludwig van",
            "publisher":"Schott Musik International",
            "location":"Seattle, WA",
            "lat_lon":"47.6115,-122.3343"
        },{
            "id":"28",
            "title":"Symphony No 3, Eroica",
            "composer":"Beethoven, Ludwig'... (length=1418)
```

That second doc (with id=28) has lat/lon that match the "pt" value in the query.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `defType=dismax` and now the results are sorted as expected.